# WCF app service taking rest of the response time for an end to end call

Tags: azure, wcf

The application deployed to azure has the following architecture:

1. ASP.NET Web Api (exposes endpoints)
2. Identity application (a new app service which is serving for authentication and authorization)
3. WCF Application (a new app service which contains the business logic)
4. Azure sql database (database and Stored Procedures)

**Data flow**:
- Web Api calls the Identity. 
- Web Api calls the WCF to get the data.
- WCF gets the data from database and returns them back to the API.

The response time for such an end to end call is higher then normal and the mos of the time is spend in WCF, even though the application code there is optimized maximally and the EF queries to database are also performing fast.

Ex. see the table below:

[image]

I have tried different solutions related to the configuring of the WCF throttling and service behaviors(maxConcurrentSessions,maxConcurrentCalls, etc).

I was thinking to create a new azure AppService and see if the issue is with the app service in azure itself, but not sure if I should do that.

Is there any suggestion or similar experience with wcf services perfroming poorly in app services in azure?

Comment: It is hard to tell what the problem is since we do not have access to the code. Did you measure the timings of the work done in the wcf call?

Comment: Yes, as you can see on the table above. The code in wcf is nothing heavy. I am sure on that. It just makes some calls to database using EF, maps the data to view models using automapper and retuns the data. Ah, and it uses MEF as an IoC container(to resolve instances). However, MEF is also used in API layer and there isn't any issue.

Comment: ...and from the table it can be seen that database queries from wcf are fast enough. Mapping the data and transfering them back is what is taking time.

Comment: If you are using an application insights instance for both, your web api and wcf service, you can find the problem easily by looking at the whole transaction and the activities between api and wcf service. Maybe it is only the transfer or even the serialization. But without any metrics we can only guess.

Comment: The table on my question shows the end to end transaction. In that example the whole time for the transaction is 693 ms, while wcf takes most of the time(477- database calls). A similar distribution is in all other calls; wcf takes more then 50% of the time. Yes, I am also thinking that the serialization or the binding is the issue. I thought maybe someone has experienced the same behavior.